# Android FusedLocationProvider and battery life

Tags: android, performance, location, android-location, power-management

I've found
[several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768048/priority-low-power-vs-priority-balanced-power-accuracy-for-google-play-service-v)
[different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874080/android-fused-location-with-balanced-profile)
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797756/what-is-the-difference-between-locationrequest-priorities-for-androids-fused-lo)
[posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210286/get-android-location-without-google-play-location-services-turned-on)
on conserving battery life with Android's
[FusedLocationProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) API.

What I'm looking is a way to intelligently select the most location accurate provider, given the state of the host's battery and some knowledge of the power drain of each one (e.g. something like [this](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider)). In other words, if the battery is nearly dead (for some predetermined value of "nearly"), the service would ideally know to avoid GPS, since that burns a lot of power, and instead use either CellID or WiFi. But I don't see anything in the FusedLocationProvider documentation along these lines.

Is there a way to do something like this with an existing API call, or would I need to roll this myself? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The screen uses the most power.

if user is on long strech of straight high way you only need to monitor accelerometers and dead rreckon  position.